# Using BeautifulSoup to scrape all shoes from popular shoes' site

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am currently trying to scrape the following site to obtain shoe information: https://www.newbalance.com/men-2/

Right now, I can retrieve 10 shoes using this code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get('https://www.newbalance.com/men-2/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
ns = soup.find("div", {"id": "category-10000-1"})
result = ns.find_all('div', class_='product product-tile')
for res in result:
    print("____________________")
    print(res)
    print("*******************************")
    print(res.find_all('a')[1].text)
    print(res.find('div',class_='product-pricing').text.split()[0])
    print(res.find("img")['data-original'])
    print(res.find('a',class_='product-image')['href'])
    print("*******************************")
```

How do I change this code so that it also obtains the shoes on the page when the "show more" button is pressed?

I only want to obtain shoe products from the site, not clothing or accessories.

Answer (score 3):

If you inspect the XHR filter in the Network tab of Developer Tool, you'll see that once you press the "Show More" button a request is sent. You can grab that url and parse it to get all the shoes.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get('https://www.newbalance.com/on/demandware.store/'
                 'Sites-newbalance_us2-Site/en_US/Search-ShowAll?cgid=10000-1'
                 '&sz=358&start=0&format=ajax&seeAll=true'
                 '&overriderenderingtemplate=override')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
result = soup.find_all('div', class_='product product-tile')
for res in result:
    print("*******************************")
    print(res.find_all('a')[1].text)
    print(res.find('div', class_='product-pricing').text.split()[0])
    print(res.find("img")['data-original'])
    print(res.find('a', class_='product-image')['href'])
    print("*******************************")

print(f"\nFound total shoes: {len(result)}")
```

This gets you 358 shoes.

```
...
*******************************
Court 806
$114.99
https://nb.scene7.com/is/image/NB/mc806w_nb_02_i?$pdpflexf2$
https://www.newbalance.com/pd/court-806/MC806.html?dwvar_MC806_style=MC806W
*******************************

Found total shoes: 358
```

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know, You should use their API to retrieve the shoes.

If you still want to use beautifulsoup then you might have to simulate the **show more** button using selenium library and then parse the HTML page.